# Streaming from a redis channel through a phoenix channel

Tags: redis, elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-channels

I am currently trying to replace [actioncable](/questions/tagged/actioncable) with a small phoenix app. What I need to do is get information from a [redis](/questions/tagged/redis) channel and stream it to an [ember](/questions/tagged/ember) client. I have been attempting to use Redis.PuSub and the Phoenix Redis adapter, but haven't been able to fully cover the functionality we currently have.

The current functionality works like this:

Our server receives a request from a user and logs some output to a Redis channel.
That channel's name is a combination of a string and a key.
The Ember client then makes a request to action-cable with the same key.
Action-cable then streams the logged information from the Redis channel with the same name.
What I need to know is how to start listening to a Redis channel with a given name when the user makes a request & stream that information continuously to the client. I've managed to get one or the other but not both.

I've been banging my head of this for over a day now so any help at all is massively appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: First of all, do you need Redis? i.e is that all happening on the same server?

Comment: Redis is still being used for two other services, one of which is the rails app to communicate and share data. So its pretty much a requirement at the moment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So in order to solve this issue I did the following.

Firstly I setup Redix.PubSub as a dependency as per the [docs](https://hexdocs.pm/redix_pubsub/Redix.PubSub.html). Then in the channel I did :

```
defmodule MyApp.ChannelName do
  use Phoenix.Channel

  def join(stream_name, _message, socket) do
    # Open a link to the redis server
    {:ok, pubsub} = Redix.PubSub.start_link()

    # Subscribe to the users stream
    Redix.PubSub.subscribe(pubsub, stream_name, self())

    {:ok, socket}
  end

  # Avoid throwing an error when a subscribed message enters the channel
  def handle_info({:redix_pubsub, redix_pid, :subscribed, _}, socket) do
    {:noreply, socket}
  end

  # Handle the message coming from the Redis PubSub channel
  def handle_info({:redix_pubsub, redix_pid, :message, %{channel: channel, payload: message}}, socket) do
    # Push the message back to the user
    push socket, "#{channel}", %{message: message}
    {:noreply, socket}
  end
end
```

In my case I required the user to sign up with a channel with some name e.g. `channel_my_api_key`. I would then start listening on the redis channel `channel_my_api_key` and stream the information back to the user via the `push` function. Note broadcast can be substituted for push.

Credit also to Alex Garibay from the Elixir forums that helped me get to the solution. You can find the thread [here](https://elixirforum.com/t/streaming-from-a-redis-channel-through-a-phoenix-channel/1885/7).